# 重み付き有向グラフがうまく生成されない

Tags: network, julia

juliaを用いて、重みつきネットワークを生成させようとしています。
[このサイト](https://github.com/inguar/Junet.jl)に書いてある通りに動かしてのですが、一部うまくいきません。issueを投げたほうが良いのかもしれませんが、慣れているのでこちらで質問させていただきました。

```
using Junet

g = Graph(2)
addedge!(g,1,2) #_____ここまではうまく動く

#g[1, 2, :weight] = 3　　#ここがエラーになる
plot(g)
```

エラーです

```
MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::Graph{UInt32,UInt32,Junet.Forward,Junet.Multi}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Symbol)
Closest candidates are:
  setindex!(::Graph, ::Any, ::Integer, !Matched::Colon, ::Symbol) at C:\JuliaPkg\dev\Junet\src\graph_operations.jl:387
  setindex!(::Graph, ::Any, !Matched::Colon, ::Integer, ::Symbol) at C:\JuliaPkg\dev\Junet\src\graph_operations.jl:388
  setindex!(::Graph, ::Any, ::Any, !Matched::Symbol) at C:\JuliaPkg\dev\Junet\src\graph_operations.jl:380
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at In[31]:8
```

中身の要素数の指定がおかしいと書いてあるみたいですが、参考さいとには特定のノード間のエッジの重みを変えたいときにはg[1,2,:weight]=任意の重み　とすれば良いと書いてあると認識しているのですが、うまくいきません。

情報共有として投稿させていただきます。

追記）
`g[:,:weight] = 1.3`とすると、

```
2-element Junet.ConstantAttribute{Float64,1,getfield(Junet, Symbol("##3#4")){Graph{UInt32,UInt32,Junet.Forward,Junet.Multi}}}:
 1.3
 1.3
```

と、2点間の間のエッジでなく、ノードに値がついてしまいます。g[1,2,:weight]=1.3とすると、やはりエラーが起きてしまいます。

Comment: タイトルが「有効グラフ」とありますが、「有向グラフ」の誤字でしょうか？

Comment: すみません、ケアレスミスです。間違えました。

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/inguar/Junet.jl/blob/master/src/graph_operations.jl#L389
呼び出そうとしてるメソッドがコメントアウトされてるので、エラーが出てるのでしょう。
元をたどると、実装部分で使われてるedgeidsが#FIXMEとなっているので、それに伴ってのことだと思われます。